# time complexity of strangely nested loops

Tags: loops, big-o, time-complexity

```
for(i=1;i<n*n;i++)
    for(k=1,l=1;l<n;k=k+2,l=l+k)
        foo;
```

How would I estimate the time complexity of a construct like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this loop by loop:

The outer loop is from 1 to n squared, therefore `O(n^2)`
The inner loop is from 1 to n but the steps are 1, 4, 9, 16... instead of 1, 2, 3, 4..., therefore `O(sqrt(n))`

Nested loops multiply the complexity, so we go for `O(sqrt(n)*n^2)` or `O(n^2.5)`

Comment: although l isn't incrementing at a constant rate in the inner loop - I think it's more like O(sqrt(n)) for the inner one.

Answer (score 1):

Generally ridecar2 is correct but be careful because sometimes you can get a trick question where e.g. the size of your data is n*n array, which means that iteration of that array is o(n) not o(n^2) despite the fact that it looks like:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
 for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
     doStuff();
```

Comment: are you referring to mine or his? My example is definitely O(n) but in his case n doesn't necessarily have to be the size of data so I would recommend caution.

Comment: yours, as it's a loop that executes n times inside another loop that executes n times giving `O(n^2)`

Comment: That's why it is a trick question. O(something) describes efficiency in relation to data size. Let's replace array n*n with array k*k. which means that size of the data n=k*k. the algorithm performs O(k^2) ops k^2 is your n which means that the iteration of the array is O(n)

Comment: Damn, I'd forgotten to assert that the data size was n or redefine things. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm can be simplified like the following:

```
for ( i = 1; i < n * n; i ++ )
    for ( l = 1 ; l * l < n ; l = l ++ )
        foo;
```

Therefore, you can represent it using Sigma Notation to formally infer the exact order of growth complexity, like the following:

[image]